# Energy density of an iron spring?

Tags: potential-energy, spring

What is the approximate energy density of an iron spring under maximum tension/compression?  Is there a difference in energy density in compression vs. tension?  According to [this](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/energy-storage-density-of-coiled-springs.365749/), the equation for calculating the energy density of a spring is

```
1/2*K*x^2
```

The `x` in the formula is defined in that post as the yield point (I think), which in iron with a grain diameter of 5*10^-2 mm has a lower limit of 135 MPa according to [this](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/lower-yield-point-iron-average-grain-diameter-5-x10-2-mm-135-mpa-19-500-psi--grain-diamete-q4488714).  However, the variable `k` is never defined.

**How can I calculate the energy density of an iron spring?**

Comment: it might be better to post this question on the engineering stack exchange.

Comment: If I don't get suitable answers here, I'll consider it.

Comment: You can calculate the spring constant $k$ using a [spring constant calculator](https://www.acxesspring.com/espanol/spring-constant-calculator.html). The spring constant depends on both the material and the geometry.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Thank-you.  That was exactly what I was looking for.  I can now calculate everything I need to.